# Show limited portion of array based on currentPage value using slice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to build a Pagination component in ReactJs. I am currently attempting to get the component to show two indices before and after the currentPage. For example, if currentPage is 3, it should show 1 2 3 4 5 and if currentPage is 6 it should show 4 5 6 7 8 and so on. If an index is unavailable it won't be shown, like for the first page there won't be two indices before it, so it would simply show 1 2 3.

I have an Array with the list of totalPages being sent as props as well as the currentPage. I have the following logic, where I use splice to limit the contents of the array

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from './Pagination.css';

const Pagination = ( {totalPages, currentPage, updateOnPageChange} ) => {
    let curr = currentPage,start = 0,end = parseInt(currentPage)+2;
    {(curr == 1 || curr == 2 )? start = 0 : start = parseInt(currentPage) - 2 }
    console.log(start + " " + currentPage +" "+totalPages+" "+end);
    return (
        <div className="pagination-div">
            <div className="pagination-wrapper">
                {
                    Array(totalPages).fill(1).slice(start,end).map((el, i) => (
                         <div className="number-wrapper" onClick={updateOnPageChange}>
                            {  
                               i+1 == currentPage ? <p className="current"><strong>{i+1}</strong</p>:<p>{i+1}</p>
                            }
                         </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Pagination.propTypes = {
    totalPages: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    currentPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    updateOnPageChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Pagination;
```

The component works fine for currentPage 1 and 2, after that however, it shows all the pages upto 4 only. I can't figure out why this would be happening and I have 34 pages hence I know that I have not run out of pages.

Any help will be most appreciated

**EDIT** - I notice that the if I put zero or any other number as the first argument of the slice function, it displays numbers upto currentPage + 2 (so the logic works one way). The moment i add an expression or variables it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping indices of the sliced array and that is why you always get range from `0` to `end - 1` as the array after slicing is always indexed from 0. In order to fix your code, first, `map` the ones to correct page indices and after that perform a `slice`.

```
Array(totalPages)
.fill(1)
.map((el, i) => i + 1)
.slice(start,end)
.map(pageNumber => (
  <div className="number-wrapper" onClick={updateOnPageChange}>
  { pageNumber == currentPage 
  ? <p className="current"><strong>{pageNumber}</strong</p>
  : <p>{pageNumber}</p>
  }
  </div>
)
```